# Push data in to JSON on ng-blur using angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I have one text box. When I type something in that text box and click anywhere then the content in the text box want to push in JSON. 
Here is my text box code

```
<input type="text" name="treatmentCost" class="form-control" ng-model="addTemplate" />
```

Here is my JSON

```
$scope.existingTemp = [{"name": "template1"},{"name": "template2"},{"name": "template3"},{"name": "template4"},{"name": "template5"}];
```

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directive for that.

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="addTemplate" ng-blur="addValueToJson(addTemplate)"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addValueToJson = function(value){
   var newObj = {name: value};
   $scope.existingTemp.push(newObj);
};
```

This is working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shepard_one/HB7LU/10269/)** for you.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.10"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.data=[];
      $scope.fill=function(){
        $scope.data.push("name:"+$scope.addTemplate);
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.data)));
      }
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <input type="text" name="treatmentCost" class="form-control" ng-model="addTemplate" ng-blur="fill()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rR0Sl0ZE7xTrZmIonVAI?p=preview